# How do I decrypt the text which is already encrypted in the past using Java AES 256 Decryption?

Tags: java, security, encryption, aes

I'm fresh bee for writing Java AES GCM encryption and decryption.

I have the need to encrypt the given password using Java AES GCM and stored in config file. Then, decrypt them later and get the same password to get the security clearance.

Using the below program from the [link](https://www.javainterviewpoint.com/java-aes-256-gcm-encryption-and-decryption/)

It perfectly works for encryption and decryption if we use the same SecretKey at the same time.

But, I wanted to do encryption very first time and decryption later as many time should yield the same text got encrypted.

Can you please help to get the program works for the decryption for later time?

```
package com.javainterviewpoint;

import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Base64;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.GCMParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AES_GCM_Example
{
    static String plainText = "This is a plain text which need to be encrypted by Java AES 256 GCM Encryption Algorithm";
    public static final int AES_KEY_SIZE = 256;
    public static final int GCM_IV_LENGTH = 12;
    public static final int GCM_TAG_LENGTH = 16;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        keyGenerator.init(AES_KEY_SIZE);
       
        // Generate Key
        SecretKey key = keyGenerator.generateKey();
        byte[] IV = new byte[GCM_IV_LENGTH];
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        random.nextBytes(IV);

        System.out.println("Original Text : " + plainText);
        
        byte[] cipherText = encrypt(plainText.getBytes(), key, IV);
        System.out.println("Encrypted Text : " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText));
        
        String decryptedText = decrypt(cipherText, key, IV);
        System.out.println("DeCrypted Text : " + decryptedText);
    }

    public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] plaintext, SecretKey key, byte[] IV) throws Exception
    {
        // Get Cipher Instance
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
        
        // Create SecretKeySpec
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getEncoded(), "AES");
        
        // Create GCMParameterSpec
        GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(GCM_TAG_LENGTH * 8, IV);
        
        // Initialize Cipher for ENCRYPT_MODE
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, gcmParameterSpec);
        
        // Perform Encryption
        byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plaintext);
        
        return cipherText;
    }

    public static String decrypt(byte[] cipherText, SecretKey key, byte[] IV) throws Exception
    {
        // Get Cipher Instance
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
        
        // Create SecretKeySpec
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getEncoded(), "AES");
        
        // Create GCMParameterSpec
        GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(GCM_TAG_LENGTH * 8, IV);
        
        // Initialize Cipher for DECRYPT_MODE
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, gcmParameterSpec);
        
        // Perform Decryption
        byte[] decryptedText = cipher.doFinal(cipherText);
        
        return new String(decryptedText);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented by @Erwin Bolwidt [**edit:** the answer with the comment was deleted by the author.] the problem in your code is that you need to use the same initialization vector (IV) for decryption that was used for encryption.

You need to store the IV alongside with the ciphertext and use this IV for decryption.

When transporting the ciphertext e.g. by email you could Base64 encode the IV and ciphertext to a string encoding and later on decryption you run the Base64 decoding before using this data for decryption. If you store the ciphertext in a database as a byte array you could store the IV in another database field or prepend the IV to the ciphertext [and strip it off for later decryption].

Comment: Thank you for reply...  I stored byte value of IV as encoded string which generated RandomNumber during encryption. Later, just called the decrypt method with decrypted value of IV to see that works. Now, I got TagMismatch error. Any suggestion please

Comment: What is "encoded string" ? Is it a Base64 encoded string or something like "new String(iv)" ?

Comment: I've tried both. Get the byte of IV. Then, convert to Base64 encoded String and decode as byte. Also, new String(IV). Can you please share me if you have quick example if possible.

Comment: The link provides a full running example for AES GCM string encryption (disclaimer: I'm the author) https://github.com/java-crypto/cross_platform_crypto/blob/main/AesGcm256StringEncryption/AesGcm256StringEncryption.java

Comment: Thank you again ! unfortunately, getting  java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size exception when I try running this program in local. Not sure anything am doing wrong. Please advise

Comment: If my sample program runs into "illegal key size exception" then your Java (8 ?) is not prepared for AES key sizes > 128. Three choices remain: a) update your Java version, b) install Java policies that allow you to use AES key lengths > 128, c) use AES GCM with key size 128 bit = 16 bytes.

Comment: You'da man ! Java version is the issue. Upgrade and tested. Its ROCKING !